What is a good substitute for Mace?
For a Malai Kofta recipe I am supposed to add:

2 single strands of mace or a light pinch of ground mace powder

But, I just cannot find anyplace near me that sells Mace.
Are there any substitutes that I should try?
I also can't get it delivered fast enough by mail (although I may so that I can have it for future meals).
Thank you so much in advance.

In reference to using Nutmeg @SAJ14SAJ writes:

The flavors are very similar (they are different parts of the fruit of the same tree, nutmeg being the nut itself, and mace being a covering that grows around the shell), although nutmeg tends to be slightly stronger and more forward.

Source: Can Nutmeg be substituted in for Mace?
